# use pattern matching to specify a width or height

Tags: css

I wan't to do something like this:

```
[class *=height-] {
  height:$value px;
}
```

Where value is grabbed from the class name...like:

```
<div class="height-100"></div>
```

Is that possible in css.

Comment: It may be possible to jig something up with data attributes but I would recommend against.

Comment: with JavaScript, yes, not sure about SASS

Comment: You would have to use a CSS preprocessor to get that value.  However, CSS should primarily be used to describe content rather than presentation, so `height-100` is not a great CSS class name.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#reference) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which support variables. They create ready-to-use .css files and support variables, functions, mixins and much more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this with CSS, but that seems to violate the separation of style and content. Consider using LESS or SASS for this, but it is simple in Javascript.

```
var height=document.getElementById("div_to_use").className.split("-")[1];
document.getElementById("div_to_use").style.height=height;
```